# Preciso Fazer Um Botão Que Obtenha Os Valores Que Estão Dentro De Uma Td

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso obter o valor que está dentro de produto-id.

```
</thead>
<tr>
   <td>
     <button onclick="loading('carregando');" produto-id="70056057210" type="button" class="btn btn-info click-produto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></button>
    </td>
```

Já testei de varias formas como:

```
 $(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[produto-id]').data('id');
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

E Abaixo O Botão:

```
<td><button class="btn-danger">Recuperar Id</button></td>
```

Porem Recebo

> "undefined"

No Alerta Como Devo prosseguir?

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma.

```
 var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('button[produto-id]').data('id');
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119173/discussion-on-answer-by-bruno-bafilli-preciso-fazer-um-botao-que-obtenha-os-valo)

Answer (score 0):

> Resposta rápida:
>
> ```
> var id = $(this).parents('tr').find('[produto-id]').attr('produto-id');
> ```

Não está claro na pergunta, mas dá a entender que:

- possui uma tabela.
- em cada linha dessa tabela há dois botões:

  1. O primeiro botão não é [identificado](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) seu atributo classe é `class="btn btn-info click-produto"` e possui um atributo não padrão `produto-id`.
  2. O segundo botão também não identificado, seu atributo classe é `class="btn-danger"` e possui um evento associado a ele.
- o objetivo do código é, através do evento associado ao segundo botão, obter o valor do atributo `produto-id` pertencente ao primeiro botão, que esteja na mesma linha do segundo botão e exibi-lo num alert.

> Devo o aconselhar a não utilizar atributos não padrão. O ideal é utilizar
> atributos [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*). Os atributos globais `data-*` permitem que informações
> proprietárias sejam trocadas via script entre o *HTML* e sua representação *DOM*.

Supondo que haja algum empecilho que o impeça de utilizar um atributo data, o que pode  fazer é a partir do segundo botão do subir na [hierarquia do documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM/Referencia_do_DOM/Introdu%C3%A7%C3%A3o) até encontrar a linha cujo é pai do elemento e então descer na hierarquia buscando em seus filhos o elemento cujo possui o atributo `produto-id` e obter esse valor:

- Suba hierarquia de ancestrais use o método [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) com o seletor `'tr'`.
- Busque os descendentes de um elemento use o método [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) com o seletor `'[produto-id]'` que seleciona os elementos que [possuem o atributo especificado](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).
- Obtenha o valor de um atributo, do primeiro elemento de uma seleção,  com o método [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) passando o nome do atributo `'produto-id'` como seletor.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').find('[produto-id]').attr('produto-id');
    alert(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="loading('carregando');" produto-id="70056057210" type="button" class="btn btn-info click-produto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">...‍♂️...</button>
    </td>
    <td><button class="btn-danger">Recuperar Id</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="loading('carregando');" produto-id="88943346723" type="button" class="btn btn-info click-produto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">...‍♂️...</button>
    </td>
    <td><button class="btn-danger">Recuperar Id</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```